# How to change the name of the key in eloquent response data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I use eloquent relationship between Two models tweets and users table.and run this snippets:

```
$list = User::with('tweets')->all();
return response($list,200);
```

my data looks like this one:

```
{
  id:1,
  name:John,
  tweets:
   [
    {id:1,content:"test"},
    {id:2,content:"test2"}
   ]
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How to change the `tweets` key to the for example `comments` in the response data?
2. How to get just `content` key from tweets?

Comment: I strongly recommend reading [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources) documentation.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: salaam daadaash. There isn't a shortcut to learn it. You have to read.

Comment: Do you use a Collection and API Resources?@mostafa-saadatnia

Comment: @FaridVatani no...can you give me an example?

Comment: OK, First Answer my question. Do you want to display each user's tweets as an API?@mostafa-saadatnia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming this is one to many relations

question 1 : change `tweets()` to `comments()` in parent model

```
class parent_model extends Model
{
  protected $hidden = ['primary_key'];

  public function tweets(){ //change to comments
    return $this->hasMany(Child::class);
  }
  //rest of the code
}
```

question 2 : `User::with('comments:{foreign key must included},selected_table')->all();`
if you want to hide primary_key You better use the `$hidden` property on your Eloquent model then u can select desired columns to be displayed in response.
also set relation `belongsTo` function in child model to be included in `$hidden` property.

```
class child_relation_model extends Model
{
  protected $hidden = ['primary_key', 'user'];

  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class);
  }
  //rest of the code
}
```